# Find a pattern and replace everything following that pattern with another pattern

Tags: sed, replace

I have data like this:

```
1_filename=$MYPATH/abcd/your_path/img.bin
2_filename=$MYPATH/cdef/jdskjdk/img2.bin
1_filesize=10mb
2_filesize=12mb
```

My expected output is:

```
1_filename=img.bin
2_filename=img2.bin
1_filesize=10mb
2_filesize=12mb
```

How could I achieve this using `sed` command?

Answer (score 6):

Replace the `=` and everything after it until the final `/` with simply `=`.

```
sed 's/=.*\//=/'
```

Example

```
$ cat foo.txt
1_filename=$MYPATH/abcd/your_path/img.bin
2_filename=$MYPATH/cdef/jdskjdk/img2.bin
1_filesize=10mb
2_filesize=12mb
$ sed 's/=.*\//=/' foo.txt
1_filename=img.bin
2_filename=img2.bin
1_filesize=10mb
2_filesize=12mb
$
```

Comment: I  have nore data with = i.e

Comment: I have more data in the file , just edited my question.

Comment: So you want lines like `1_filesize=10mb` completely removing then ?

Comment: No I dont want to remove 1_filesize.  It should still be there. I need to search for filename and then replace everything after '=' with only *.bin(i,e remove the path and keep only bin name)

Comment: I think the expected output needs an overhaul then ?

Comment: Sorry , corrected just now

Comment: If you don't use `/` as the delimiter then  you don't need to escape it in the script - `'s:=.*/:=:'`